# How to link css file inside bundle - Symfony 2.8

Tags: twig, symfony-2.8

I generated new bundle and I have styles.css file in following path`src/AdminBundle/Resource/public/styles.css`. In my base.html.twig file I have link (templates/head.html.twig)

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/adminbundle/css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But this giving error not found file. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files from src/AdminBundle/Resource/public/styles.css  **are not** copied automaticlly  to  web/bundles

You need to to run command

```
php app/console assets:install
```